# How can I format time output in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

In my power automate flow, I have an action that give time output in this format: 2022-12-01T18:52:50.0000000Z
How can I take this output and format as yyyy/mm/dd .
I want to use the time output as string for a folder structure.

Comment: Sorry, its cloud flows

Comment: Yep, cool. Answer is there anyway.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one finding microsoft naming convention confusing :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime

Assuming you have a variable called `DateTime`, you would create another variable and use this expression ...

```
formatDateTime(Variables('DateTime'), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward.

Use the ***Convert datetime to text*** function
[image]

In the **Format to use** dropdown select *Custom*
and specify the format how you would like it to appear.
[image]

*yyyy/MM/hh* will give you 2022/12/01

*HH-mm-ss* will give you 18-52-50

[image]